# Incremented unique variables in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a scenario like this:

```
$data = "A,B,C=>fruit'\n'D,E,F=>veggie'\n'A,D=>mix"
$rules = array_map('trim', explode('\n', $data));
$i = 1;
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
   $letter_group."_".$i = array_map('trim', explode('=>', $rule));
   $letter.$i = array_map('trim', explode(',', $letter_group."_".$i[0]));
   $group.$i = array_map('trim', explode(',', $letter_group."_".$i[1]));
   $i++;
   var_dump($letter.$i);
   var_dump($group.$i);
}
```

But this doesn't work. How to get these outputs?

```
$letter1 = array('A','B','C');
$letter2 = array('D','E','F');
$letter3 = array('A','D');
$group1 = array('fruit');
$group2 = array('veggie');
$group3 = array('mix');
```

Comment: `$letter_group."_".$i` `$letter.$i` will these *ever* work as the left-hand value of an assignment? Use `array`.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the check by an answer you like ANd by clicking the up arrow right above it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, you should try to put your values in an array (+1 for that).  I think this is what you want:

```
<?php
$data = "A,B,C=>fruit'\n'D,E,F=>veggie'\n'A,D=>mix";
$data=str_replace("'","",$data);//you don't need the single quotes in there
$rules = explode("\n", $data);
$array=array();
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    $ar=explode("=>",$rule);
    $array[$ar[1]]=explode(",",$ar[0]);
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

This prints out:

```
Array
(
[fruit] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C
    )

[veggie] => Array
    (
        [0] => D
        [1] => E
        [2] => F
    )

[mix] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => D
    )

)
```

**EDIT FROM QUESTION BELOW:**

While I would advise storing it in an multidemisional array as above, if you **had** to put them in individual variables, you can just assign the variables from the array built above:

```
$letter1=$ar['fruit']
$letter2=$ar['veggie'];
$letter3=$ar['mix'];
//etc ....
```

Can I ask, why do you need these in individual variables?

Comment: Thanks Landon for your heads up. The problems are:

Comment: The problems are:
1. I need unique variables (that's why I use $i to define a unique variable for each single string of the data) to be used in the methods.
2. How can I assign each array array member into unique variables?

Comment: Again thanks for the heads up. The reason I need unique variables for each individual data because I need to compare the user's input data with the system configuration data.

Anyway, I will try to work around with your heads up first. I'll come back once I have better words to explain more clear why I need unique individual variable for each data.

Comment: great, if you like my answer, please consider accepting and up voting it